# Precise drawing using React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I need some help in figuring out how to draw precisely in React Native. I have done this kind of thing before on (native) iOS, but not yet on Android, so potentially I may be missing an Android-thing but I would preferably solve this using only React Native methods without resorting to implementing custom views.

I'm trying to draw a staff of a musical score, for example:

[image: Example of a staff]

I'm doing this using a React Native `FlatList` in horizontal mode. I'm drawing the vertical lines as separators and the horizontal lines inside the content cells. At this point that's all I'm concerned with, not yet the numbers etc.

I have tried two ways of drawing this with React Native:

1. PNGs; I supply normal, @2x and @3x versions and render them in `ImageBackground` tags. This works on iOS but on Android the lines don't line up perfectly so that you some that the vertical and horizontal lines don't connect nicely, there are gaps, and vertically the components don't get the same size so that they are too short. Is this because of the @2x and @3x being pixel-perfect for iOS, but still need to be scaled for Android?
2. SVG (`react-native-svg`); this gives similar issues. Again on iOS results are quite good, but on Android pixels don't line up properly. To illustrate this, see the following three screenshots.

SVG on iOS: close to perfect (but not 100%):
[image: iOS]

SVG on Android low-res device (emu): very strange how the heights of different parts are very different:

[image: Android low res]

SVG on Android high-res device (emu): horizontal line is not continuous and vertical lines go outside of staff above and below:

[image: Android high res]

I don't understand why this turns out the way it does on Android. I'm not sure if I'm using the right way to accomplish this. **What method should I use for this?** Any help is much appreciated!

Below is the relevant source code. It's in ClojureScript but even if you're not familiar with it, you should be able to recognize the way the SVGs are built. I carefully used half-pixel values for the line coordinates and square endings, so that everything should theoretically line up exactly on the pixels.

```clj
(defn bar-lines [width]
  (take 5 (map (fn [y] ^{:key (str y)}
                 [:> Line {:x1 0.5 :y1 y :x2 (+ 0.5 (dec width)) :y2 y
                           :stroke-width 1 :stroke "black"
                           :stroke-linecap "square"}])
               (iterate (partial + 8) 0.5))))

(defn cell [details]
  (let [item (details "item")
        num (item "measureNumber")]
    [:> ViewOverflow {:style {:width 68 :height 65}}
     [:> Svg {:height 34 :width 68 :view-box "0 0 68 33"
              :style {:position "absolute" :bottom 0}}
      (bar-lines 68)]]))

(defn single-line-separator []
  [:> ViewOverflow {:style {:width 1 :height 65}}
   [:> Svg {:height 34 :width 1 :view-box "0 0 1 33"
            :style {:position "absolute" :bottom 0}}
    [:> Line {:x1 0.5 :y1 0.5 :x2 0.5 :y2 32.5 :stroke-linecap "square" :stroke-width 1 :stroke "black"}]]])

(defn double-line-separator []
  [:> ViewOverflow {:style {:width 3 :height 65}}
   [:> Svg {:height 34 :width 3 :view-box "0 0 3 33"
            :style {:position "absolute" :bottom 0}}
    [:> Line {:x1 0.5 :y1 0.5 :x2 0.5 :y2 32.5 :stroke-linecap "square" :stroke-width 1 :stroke "black"}]
    [:> Line {:x1 2.5 :y1 0.5 :x2 2.5 :y2 32.5 :stroke-linecap "square" :stroke-width 1 :stroke "black"}]
    (bar-lines 3)]])

(defn separator [props]
  (if (show-double-bar? (.-measureNumber (.-leadingItem props)))
    (double-line-separator)
    (single-line-separator)))

(defn header []
  [:> rn/View {:style {:width 15 :height 65}}
   [:> Svg {:height 34 :width 15 :view-box "0 0 15 33"
            :style {:position "absolute" :bottom 0}}
    (bar-lines 15)
    [:> Line {:x1 14.5 :y1 0.5 :x2 14.5 :y2 32.5 :stroke-linecap "square" :stroke-width 1 :stroke "black"}]]])

(defn footer []
  [:> rn/View {:style {:width 11 :height 65}}
   [:> Svg {:height 34 :width 11 :view-box "0 0 11 33"
            :style {:position "absolute" :bottom 0}}
    [:> Line {:x1 0.5 :y1 0.5 :x2 0.5 :y2 32.5 :stroke-linecap "square" :stroke-width 1 :stroke "black"}]
    [:> Line {:x1 4.5 :y1 1.5 :x2 4.5 :y2 31.5 :stroke-linecap "square" :stroke-width 3 :stroke "black"}]
    (bar-lines 3)]])

(defn Staff [styles]
  [:> rn/View styles
   [:> rn/FlatList
    {:data (clj->js (mapv (fn [n] {:key (str n) :measureNumber n}) (range 1 4)))
     :horizontal true
     :Cell-renderer-component ViewOverflow
     :List-header-component #(r/as-element [header])
     :List-footer-component #(r/as-element [footer])
     :Item-separator-component #(r/as-element [separator %])
     :render-item (fn [details] (r/as-element [cell (js->clj details)]))}]])
```